# I cant figure out why my css styling is interfering with each other?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Well I am trying to style links but for my nav is also getting affected .

I tried to position them different lexically but the block which is written afterwards  seems to have affect.

```
/*---navbar---*/
  .main-nav li a:link,a:visited{
    padding:8px 0;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.3s;
 }
.main-nav li a:hover,a:active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e58e26;

}

/*---links---*/
a:link,
a:visited {
    color: #e67e22;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e67e22;

    transition: border-bottom 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #555;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: When you comma separate a selector, it doesn't carry the previous selector with it; it's an entirely independent selector. For example, `.main-nav li a:link, a:visited` will style `.main-nav li a:link`, and `a:visited`. Because you then re-style `a:visited` later in the document, it is overridden. You want `.main-nav li a:link, .main-nav li a:visited`

Comment: Basically the  color attribute is being overriden

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
.main-nav li a:link,a:visited{
   /* style rules */
}
.main-nav li a:hover,a:active{
   /* style rules */
}
```

Each comma separated selector needs to be written in full:

```
.main-nav li a:link, .main-nav li a:visited{
   /* style rules */
}
.main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:active{
   /* style rules */
}
```